# Terraform lookup and length operands in count

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create Cloudwatch alarm but only if `engine_mode` variable equals to `provisioned`. length and lookup can't work together, by default this create alarm regardless:
`count = local.instance_count < 1 ? 1 : local.instance_count`
This want to destroy it if it is set to provisioned:
`count = local.instance_count < 1 || (local.instance_count >= 1 && local.engine_mode == "provisioned") ? 1 : 0`

in locals I have:

```
locals {
  engine_mode          = lookup(var.configuration, "engine_mode", "provisioned")
  instance_count       = lookup(var.configuration, "instance_count", 1)
}
```

`configuration` variable is sourcing from tfvars per environment:

```
environment_vars = {
  db = {
    instance_count           = 0
    engine_mode              = "serverless"
  }
}
```

configuration variable within RDS module:

```
variable "configuration" {
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}
```

RDS cluster configuration:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "this" {
  cluster_identifier              = var.name
  engine                          = local.engine
  engine_version                  = local.engine_version
  engine_mode                     = local.engine_mode
...
```

RDS instance configuration:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "this" {
  count = local.instance_count

  engine                       = local.engine
  identifier                   = "${var.name}-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier           = aws_rds_cluster.this.id
  db_subnet_group_name         = aws_db_subnet_group.this.name
  db_parameter_group_name      = element(aws_db_parameter_group.this.*.name, count.index)
  instance_class               = lookup(var.configuration, "instance_class", "db.t3.small")
  promotion_tier               = lookup(var.configuration, "promotion_tier", count.index * 10)
```

and the alarm:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu" {
  count = local.instance_count < 1 ? 1 : local.instance_count
  alarm_name                = local.instance_count < 1 ? "DB-${var.name}-CPU" : "DB-${var.name}-${count.index}-CPU"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = lookup(var.configuration, "alarm_cpuutilization_evaluation_periods", "3")
  datapoints_to_alarm       = lookup(var.configuration, "alarm_cpuutilization_evaluation_periods", "3")
  period                    = lookup(var.configuration, "alarm_cpuutilization_period", "300")
  threshold                 = lookup(var.configuration, "alarm_cpuutilization_threshold", "85")

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = local.instance_count < 1 ? var.name : "${var.name}-${count.index}"
  }
}
```

It is not my code, I inherited it and trying to understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the alarm from being created, you can create another ternary statement that forces the `count` to zero if the `engine_mode` is provisioned.
You may achieve it doing something like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cpu" {
  # prevent creation of alarm if engine_mode is provisioned, otherwise create at least one alarm
  count = local.engine_mode == "provisioned" ? 0 : local.instance_count < 1 ? 1 : local.instance_count
  # ...
}
```

I just want to point out that this solution is not very clean, but given that the code is very coupled, and I do not have a complete understanding of your domain, this solution is the "safest" to avoid creating side-effects in other parts of the module. Should this solution work or not, I suggest you to refactor the code to decouple the instance count of each resource, unless you are completely sure that two resources must *always* be created with the same cardinality.

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all. It wants to destroy all provisioned RDS instances and destroy alarm for serverless in another environment.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code, so that I could understand better the configuration you are trying?

Comment: Added more code as requested.

Comment: @DisplayName I updated the answer, let me know if you have better luck with it this time :)

Comment: Felleti, that worked! I just had to change local.engine_mode == "provisioned" to serverless. Because I want to prevent this alarm to be created if instance type is server less. This is due to different dimension in alarm configuration.